# Storing array from Parse into local array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

When I try to store arrays from Parse into a local array I can only access it within the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {...}`. When I print it outside of that block, it shows `[]`...

Code :

```
var qArray : [[Int]] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Trivia")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if objects != nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    self.qArray.append(object["mainPattern"] as! [Int])
                }
                print(self.qArray) // Prints a multi dimension array
            }
        }
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    print(self.qArray) // prints []
}
```

Comment: have you figured out the mistake you were making?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because the array hasn't been populated yet because it's running in the background. You can try using `dispatch_group` to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what **findInBackground** means.  It means the code after the callback continues to execute, so it calls **query.findInBackground....** and then it continues with the next line, which is **print(self.qArray)**.  At some point later on, it hears back from the database and it executes all the code inside the Callback, which is when the array finally gets populated.